# Android, How to bring selected custom view in the middle of screen?

Tags: android, widget, custom-component

[image]

Hi,
As you can see in above image, I created a custom view as as item of my calendar. 
In code i have repeat it for example 50 times to create calendar.

Server sends me a flag that shows which of them should be selected (in this case 09 Jun is selected).

My problem is when server sends a day which is not in screen (for example 25 Jun), That date becomes selected (the background of 25 Jun changes) but in screen i see above image (but now the background of 09 Jun changed to white color like others).

The  thing that i'm looking for is showing 25 Jun item in middle of screen. I have no idea how its possible.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. The code of mu custom view(widget) is like this:

```
public class Calendar_Item extends RelativeLayout {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private RelativeLayout rlContainer;
    private TextView tvMonth;
    private TextView tvDay;
    private ImageView imDot;

    public Calendar_Item(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public Calendar_Item(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public Calendar_Item(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        RelativeLayout calendarView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
        addView(calendarView);

        rlContainer = (RelativeLayout)  calendarView.findViewById(R.id.cal_rlContainer);
        tvMonth     = (TextView)        calendarView.findViewById(R.id.cal_month);
        tvDay       = (TextView)        calendarView.findViewById(R.id.cal_date);
        imDot       = (ImageView)       calendarView.findViewById(R.id.cal_dot);
    }



    public void setMonth(String month) {
        tvMonth.setText(month);
    }

    public void setMonth(int resId) {
        tvMonth.setText(resId);
    }

    public CharSequence getMonth() {
        return tvMonth.getText();
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        tvDay.setText(day);
    }

    public void setDay(int resId) {
        tvDay.setText(resId);
    }

    public CharSequence getDay() {
        return tvDay.getText();
    }

    public void showDot() {
        imDot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideDot() {
        imDot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        tvDay.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
        rlContainer.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    }

    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
        rlContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        rlContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

Layout XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView 
   xmlns:android            = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width     = "fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height    = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_below     = "@id/header"
   android:fadingEdgeLength = "30dip"
   android:fadingEdge       = "horizontal"
   android:scrollbars       = "none" >

   <LinearLayout 
        android:id              = "@+id/llCalendarItems"
        android:layout_width    = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation     = "horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

All calendar items sit inside of LinearLayout.

Comment: Where did you find the tutorial for horizontal calendar view?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my way which is using post delay method.

```
hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsvCalendar);
hsv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    hsv.scrollTo(selectedDay * 100, 0);
}
}, 100L);
```